# HEVC reference software : Modification to encode CTUs line by line instead of slice segments

Tags: video, encoding, mp4, video-encoding, hevc

Looking inside the `Void TEncSlice::encodeSlice` of the official HM Test software, I found that in a loop the encoder is trying to encode every CTU inside a slice segment ie  512 CTUs in a unique slice in my script example.

`for( UInt ctuTsAddr = startCtuTsAddr; ctuTsAddr < boundingCtuTsAddr; ++ctuTsAddr )`

If I would like to encode the frame line by line (ie to implement wavefront encoding) should I modify the slice segment to be equal with the frame width or is a wrong approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use ponctuation. It was pretty difficult to read your question.

If I understood correctly, one possible solution to your problem is to make the HM encode each frame with exactly one slice. Then, CTUs in your frame would be raster scanned (i.e. line by line).

As far as I remember, this is the HM's default setting. So, I think you need to tell us what your current scan is? How large is your frame? Your current slice size?

Comment: Right now I am using one big slice with raster scan. But as I mentioned to my question the HM Software encodes the CTUs in loop that fits to a slice (remember I need separated line per line encoding as individual jobs in parallel). I want to know the CTUs per line which I think is picture size / CTU size in pixels. In this case how to treat the situation when the above division is not perfect ? Is that a correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, the number of CTUs in each line is ceil(picWidth / CTUsize).

Now going back to your question, you want to compress/encode rows of CTUs in parallel. To do so, you are suggesting to set your slice width to picture width and set your slice height to CTU height (size). Then you want to implement the idea of the WPP and compress/encode slices in a pipeline with delay of one CTU with respect to the above slice. This idea should work if you properly handle (i.e. remove) all CABAC context models dependencies, if there is any.

Comment: Hey ! I think slices does not have width and heights just series of CTUs! So you suggest to define slices that each one have a number of CTUs that is equal to the number of CTUs per row . Did I understand well ? The CTUs are divisible by 64. How to manage the case the frame width is not divisible with 64 ?

Comment: You should round it to top. For example, width of 160 would give two CTUs of size 64x64 and one CTU of 64x32 (64+64+32=160).

Comment: Hi, I thought that it would round it in some way, but my concers are how this can be done in the encoding process ? Firstly does it allowed  for CTUs to  have different sizes in different parts of the frame ? Do I have to change the code or it was already done from the HM developers... ?

Comment: Of course that CTUs are allowed to have different sizes on the borders. Otherwise, HEVC wouldn't have been able to code any video other than those that have multiples of 64 pixels in width/height.

Comment: Handling different CTU sizes on borders is done automatically by the HEVC (i.e. HM)

Comment: Is that possible to use WPP and Tiles compined together at the same time ?